# JSF2 validator regex

Tags: regex, validation, jsf

I am using following regex validator, i want validation error on whitespace if entered only and allowed chars from list a-z and A-Z and _ and 'whitespace' and 0-9

Currently i have having problem with this exp it is not allowing white spaces in b/w nor in the begning.

```
<f:validateRegex pattern="^\s[a-zA-Z\s_0-9]+"/>
```

please any quick suggestion appriciated

for example.

```
" " (When user pass empty string it should fail)
" Abc hello" (It should pass)
"Hello world" (It should pass)
```

Comment: Please post some strings that you want to allow and strings you don't want. Its not clear to me, what your requirements are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[a-zA-Z\s_0-9]+\b\s*$
```